# What is a reflector class in Angular2?

Tags: angular

I am studying **Angular2** and the team is actually using a "reflector class".

It's not the first time that I met this term and I really don't know what it refers to.

What is a "reflector class" in **Angular2**?

Why is this so useful ?

Comment: I'd start researching this from a javascript or programming in general point of view, as it's uses there will likely be similar to how it's used by the team with angular 2.

Answer (score 2):

```
@Component()
@View()
```

You've probably see those attached to a class in Angular 2. The Angular team called these "annotations".

Only now an ES7 proposal from Yehuda Katz might be bringing these meta-data notations to all of JavaScript. Except they'll be called "Decorators", and you can already find [decorators in TypeScript](https://smellegantcode.wordpress.com/2015/04/02/typescript-1-5-get-the-decorators-in/).

But wait! Angular already had something called "decorators". Have to rename that, too. Who knew that concepts had name-spacing conflicts as well.

So I'm not sure what is called what these days, but if you can't wait for the dust to settle, my guess would be "reflectors" are related to the [Reflector API for decorators](https://github.com/rbuckton/ReflectDecorators), which you can read in [a future article about decorators here](http://blog.wolksoftware.com/decorators-reflection-javascript-typescript). These look very similar to 'annotations'.

Answer (score 0):

A ReflectiveDependency injection container used for instantiating objects and resolving dependencies.

You can read it from Angular Official site here [ReflectiveInjector](https://angular.io/api/core/ReflectiveInjector)